# How to convert DC to a sound wave?

Tags: ac, dc, sine

I need to convert a DC voltage to a sine wave with its amplitude being equal to that DC voltage. Is there a circuit for that, and if so, how can I arrange the frequency?

Comment: You want RMS of sinewave to equal the DC voltage or p-p or peak? What frequency range are you talking about and what load on the output are you expecting to drive. Clearly with less than about 1 volt inputted you won't get anything from the output unless of course you provide another power rail.

Comment: Please clarify your question whether you want FREQUENCY conversion, or whether you want AMPLITUDE conversion? If you don't know the difference, please study Wikipedia, etc. to learn about these properties and fix your question.

Comment: Can the frequency be anything of your choosing, is a existing signal, also a function of the input voltage, or something else?

Comment: "I need to convert a DC voltage to a sine wave" - why?

Answer (score 2):

If the DC voltage is a control voltage and you have another fixed power supply that can power an oscillator, you can switch the control voltage on and off using said oscillator and a MOSFET. This will produce a square wave having a peak to peak amplitude equal to your control voltage.

Next, apply this signal to a high-order low pass filter to convert that square wave into a sinewave. The sinewave p-p amplitude will be \$4/\pi\$ times bigger due to the filter. The sine wave purity will depend on how effectively you can filter-away the harmonics of the square wave but, a good filter (6 th order) should reduce the thrid harmonic by at least 30 dB.

If you need a variable frequency then you could consider using a high-order switched capacitor filter and a clock divider to generate the base frequency. The LTC1066 springs to mind: -

[image]

[image]

It can be wired to produce a cut-off frequency from sub 1 kHz to many tens of kHz. This is the basic limitation of this idea I propose - if you want a massive range of frequencies you are into bigger complications.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for seems to be a *AM modulator*.  There are various ways to achieve this.  The tradeoffs depend on criteria you haven't told us.

If the frequency is always the same, then a resonant circuit like a AM transmitter could be appropriate.

Amplitude-modulating a square wave is easy since you make a amplifier that clips, then modulate its power supply.  To get a sine wave, apply filtering to reduce the harmonics to a acceptable level.  This is easier if you know the frequency up front.

You could stream sine samples into a multiplying A/D, and modulate its multiply input.

You could use a digital synthesis chip, and modulate its power supply.

You could do the whole thing digitally, with the final result written to a D/A with fixed range.

You could start with a fixed sine wave, then attenuate it selectively, using feedback around the attenuator to regulate the amplitude to match the incoming signal.  I actually did this once using LEDs and light dependent resistors to control the attenuation.

Same as above, but use a digital pot.

There are many ways.  Again, you need to tell us about the other criteria.  See my comment to your question.